# python: selectively override __getattr__

Tags: python, function, methods, getattr

I have successfully overridden the `__getattr__` method in order to allow for complex behavior.  However I still would like to allow some of the `__builtin__` functions to be default.  For example, I have used `__getattr__` to handle `__add__`, `__sub__`, `__mul__`, etc.  However, the `__iadd__`, `__isub__`, `__imul__`, etc. are trying to use the `__getattr__` method and are throwing an error.  I could just define their behaviors as well, but I think that allowing these methods to run as default would be better.

Bottom line: I would like to allow `__getattr__` to filter which attributes it handles, and which it allows to run as default.

Comment: So, you have a class with a custom `__getattr__` method? Some simple example code with expected results would be helpful as it doesn't seem entirely clear what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.  I used if statements to handle groups of attributes, and then as a last resort, used `return getattr(my_cls_name, attr)` to allow any other builtin function to run normally.  So now when it realizes there is no `__iadd__` handler, it uses my `__add__` instead.  same with the other operators.